# If ${\rm rank}(R) = p$ and $R v_1 \ne 0, \cdots, R v_p \ne 0$, does $Rv \ne 0$, imply $v$ is a linear combination of $v_1, \cdots , v_p$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $R \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be rank $p$, where $p < n$, and let $v, v_1, \cdots , v_p \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

If we have $R v_1 \ne 0, \cdots, R v_p \ne 0$ where $v_1, \cdots, v_p$ are linearly independent, does $Rv \ne 0$, imply that $v$ is a linear combination of $v_1, \cdots , v_p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p<n$ we can take a basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_{n-p}\}$ of the null space of $R$ and complete it with $\{v_1,\dots,v_p\}$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (column vectors).

I claim that $Rv_i\ne0$. Indeed, $Rv_i=0$ would mean that $v_i$ is a linear combination of $\{w_1,\dots,w_{n-p}\}$, contradiction. (Actually, $\{Rv_1,\dots,Rv_p\}$ is a basis of the column space of $R$, but it's not needed for the present argument.)

Now $v=w_1+v_1$ satisfies $Rv=Rw_1+Rv_1=Rv_1\ne0$, but $v$ is not a linear combination of $\{v_1,\dots,v_p\}$.